# CCK fields disappears

Tags: entities, 5

I get informed that webforms didn't work anymore. I switched recently to a new server copying database and druapl installation folder to the new server.

What happens is that when webforms using, the fields (dates, numbers, etc) do not come up. I noticed that in the modules list are some incomplete entries like above:

[image]

I checked the CCK modules folder and reinstall the folder (cck-5.x-1.12), still the same.

I use CCK too for some fields in content types and it still works for creating and editing content, but when I create a new content type with a CCK field, it fails.

This site is scheduled to migrate to version 7, but meanwhile with version 5 should work.

Any idea where to search for reason that the (sub)modules are blank and propably won't work ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into sounds as if the file permissions are messed up; here's a checklist of things to go through:

1. Open `.info` files of those modules and verify that they exist and have all regular information (name, dependencies, version, etc.).
2. If they exist and have all info, check if they have some weird file access permissions; this could prevent Drupal from reading the content. See [file permission instructions for Linux servers](https://drupal.org/node/244924#linuxservers), specifically the commands which ensure that the proper permissions are in place:

   ```
   [root@localhost]cd /path_to_drupal_installation
   [root@localhost]chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:www-data .
   [root@localhost]find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;
   [root@localhost]find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;
   ```
3. Try replicating the issue on a clean install AND on a clean install with the same installation files.
4. If the above steps don't tell you anything and you still have the issue - hack the core, specifically `_module_parse_info_file()` function in `includes/module.inc` and do a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on the `$info` variable once it parses the file. Maybe the formatting is off, encoding or something else. This might get you a step further if everything else fails.

Hope this helps.